# No OpenID end point found

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I always use Yahoo account as open ID to login in my superuser account but it was working fine till yesterday after that it is saying **No OpenID endpoint found**.

[image]

I want to know why this problem is coming. I tried Firefox, chrome but none of them worked.

Well then I used **login using Stack Exchange** and used forget password option and created a new password, it worked and I was logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed the default Yahoo! openId endpoint to `https://me.yahoo.com`, which fixes this issue.

With you in the next build (rev 2014.9.22.1881, meta rev 2014.9.22.2591).